# Refresh video with JavaScript in a Object with embed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, embed

I am having problem refreshing the video to play.  I am calling a JS function to change the source but it is not working and I not want to refresh the page. It is a way to refresh the video with my button

Play

```
function playVideo()
{

    var fileName = "myvideo";
    var rootVideoAddress = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + "/UploadVideos/";
    var videoPath = rootVideoAddress + fileName;
    var videoObject = $('#MediaPlayerVideo');
    videoObject.find('embed').attr('src', videoPath);
}





 <div>
    <object id="MediaPlayerVideo" CLASSID="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701"
                                    standby="Loading Microsoft Windows® Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject" width="280" height="256">
                                <param name="FileName"value="http://localhost:3465/UploadVideos/myvideo0.mpg">
<param name="animationatStart" value="true">
<param name="transparentatStart" value="true">
<param name="autoStart" value="false">
<param name="showControls" value="true">
<param name="Volume" value="-450">
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" src="http://localhost:3465/UploadVideos/myvideo0.mpg" name="MediaPlayer1" width="320" height="380" autostart="0" showcontrols="1" volume="-450">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating a complete new element which just copies the values (not the whole element!) and then insert it at the place, the original element was?

Another (but uncool) idea would be something like a iframe which contains the video and can simply be reloaded at any time. But that should be the last solution you should try...

Comment: I could do this using a partial view that I am loading with and ajax call and refreshing into my page. I used the ViewBag to refresh the src